# 150+ полей в таблице MySQL - это нормально?

Tags: php, mysql

Представьте себе доску объявлений, где вы сначала выбираете категорию, а потом в зависимости от выбранной категории, вам предлагают заполнить определенные поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, если выбрать категорию "автокраны", то поля для заполнения будут другие.
Все записывается в БД, и потом выводится на сайте.

Решил это делать сам, поэтому вопрос как раз к подходу. PHP + MySql.
Пока только начал делать, но планирую создать в php около 150-200 полей (input) для разных категорий. Соотвественно столько же полей в структуре таблицы БД, которая отвечает за эти объявления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А для пользователя показывать к заполнению определенные поля, с помощью js (менять классы, дисплей нон).
Незаполненные поля игнорировать, как во время добавления в БД, так и во время извлечения на фроненд.

Это нормальный подход, или есть что-то лучше? Если что, я нуб, но могу потратить немного балишка на фрилансе, если это действительно нужно.

Соотвественно вопрос к нагрузке. Долго ли будет обрабатываться форма после заполнения полей, и нажатия на "сохранить"?
Увеличится ли время загрузки страницы объявления (не админка)?

Сейчас на сайте 3000 объявлений, посещаемость 300 чел в сутки.
Максимум что можно будет выжать с этого сайта, при невероятно оптимистичном раскладе - 5000 в сутки.

Comment: *150+ полей в таблице MySQL - это нормально?* - нет. Смотрите в сторону EAV (Модель Сущность-Атрибут-Значение)

Comment: Лучше сделать поле с кодом типом объекта и кодом объекта из соответствующей таблицы.

Comment: Сергей Мишин, это оно: https://habr.com/ru/post/45935/ ?

Becouse, не понял.
Если что, то каждая категория (вид спецтехники) имеет свой уникальный value

Comment: @Amigo9876 *имеет свой уникальный value* - ну вот EAV расшифровывается как Entity-Attribute-**Value**. . Так да - оно, правда статья очень старая, нужно искать что-то современное. Наверняка на гитхабе есть (в поисковике стоит покопаться). А так да, оно

Comment: У тебя MYSQL умрет даже с индексами, фильтруя по 150 полям.